# Django - Check diference between old and new value when overriding save method

Tags: django, orm, django-models, django-signals

thanks for your time.

I'm on Django 1.4, and I have the following code: Its the overriden save method for my `Quest` model.

```
@commit_on_success
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from ib.quest.models.quest_status_update import QuestStatusUpdate
    created = not self.pk

    if not created:
        quest = Quest.objects.get(pk=self)
        # CHECK FOR SOME OLD VALUE
    super(Quest, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I couldn't find out a smart way of doing this. It seems very silly to me to have to make a new query for the object i'm currently updating in order to find out an old instance value.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you all.

Francisco

Comment: what is the context of the update and save? ie. in a view directly on the model or via ModelForm etc. ?

Comment: Well, is this really relevant? I'm on save method, updating an instance. But anyway, this call is made from a view, and there I called `quest.save()`

Comment: I'm not sure there is clean way to do this. You may pass old object to `save()` method or query it in `save()` as you are doing it.

Comment: Yes it is relevant. If you were using a modelform it stores the instance (old values) and new values within its self. So if you override the its save() you could come the field value and self.instance field value. Doing it directly on the model - I use signals as suggested below. I will put an example using django-reversion.

Comment: hummmm... this is very nice! Thanks for the insight. I'll look it up!

Answer (score 20):

You can store the old value inside the init method:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.old_my_field = self.my_field

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    print self.old_my_field
    print self.my_field
```

You can probably use deepcopy or something alike to copy the whole object for later use in the save and delete methods.

Comment: Super simple and easy to read. Plus it works perfectly. Excellent solution.

Answer (score 11):

Django doesn't cache the old values of the model instance, so you need to do that yourself or perform another query before save.

One common pattern is to use a pre-save signal (or put this code directly in your save() method, as you've done):

```
old_instance = MyModel.objects.get(pk=instance.pk)
# compare instance with old_instance, and maybe decide whether to continue
```

If you want to keep a cache of the old values, then you would probably do that in your view code:

```
from copy import deepcopy
object = MyModel.objects.get(pk=some_value)
cache = deepcopy(object)

# Do something with object, and then compare with cache before saving
```

There was [a recent discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/django-developers/CVST-LdB-SE) on django-developers about this as well, with some other possible solutions.

Comment: thank you for the solution. This works but in case you use `save_as` the pk is set to `None`. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

I am checking the difference to old values using a django-reversion signal, but the same logic would apply to the save signals. The difference for me being that I want to save whether the field was saved or not.

```
@receiver(reversion.pre_revision_commit)
def it_worked(sender, **kwargs):
    currentVersion = kwargs.pop('versions')[0].field_dict
    fieldList = currentVersion.keys()
    fieldList.remove('id')
    commentDict = {}
    print fieldList
    try:
        pastVersion = reversion.get_for_object(kwargs.pop('instances')[0])[0].field_dict
    except IndexError:
        for field in fieldList:
            commentDict[field] = "Created"
        comment = commentDict
    except TypeError:
        for field in fieldList:
            commentDict[field] = "Deleted"
        comment = commentDict
    else:
        for field in fieldList:
            try:
                pastTest = pastVersion[field]
            except KeyError:
                commentDict[field] = "Created"
            else:       
                if currentVersion[field] != pastTest:
                    commentDict[field] = "Changed"
                else:
                    commentDict[field] = "Unchanged"
        comment = commentDict
    revision = kwargs.pop('revision')
    revision.comment = comment
    revision.save()
    kwargs['revision'] = revision
    sender.save_revision
```