# Django how to save object status in signals?

Tags: django

I am using signals in my model. The status of blog post will be pending for admin approval when any user try to edit existing blog post. But when I trying to change status from `pending` to `published` from my admin panel, it's keeping the old status `pending`.

Here is my code:

**models.py**

```
def post_update(sender,instance,*args,**kwargs):
   if instance:
       instance = Blog.objects.filter(is_published="published").update(is_published="pending")

post_save.connect(Blog.post_update,sender=Blog)
```

Comment: Because when you change the status to `published` in the admin panel your signal handler fires up again and reverts it back to `pending`. You also seem to change _all_ `published` posts to `pending`, not only the one that has been just saved.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks for your comment. How to solve it and change new status published?

Comment: You can't do that using the signal handler because it executes _after_ the object has been saved, so you have no way of knowing the previous status. I would override the `.save()` method of the model instead of using signals and check the previous status. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12960258/django-check-diference-between-old-and-new-value-when-overriding-save-method) for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a third status (for example, `approved`) and let your signal handler or `.save()` method use that as a transition state. Here is an example that uses the `.save()` method instead of a signal handler (which I prefer because it is more readable):

```
class Blog(model.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ("pending", "Pending"),
        ("approved", "Approved"),
        ("published", "Published")) 
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)

    # ... your existing fields

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.status == "published":
            self.status = "pending"
        elif self.status == "approved":
            self.status = "published
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

After this change you should set the status of the `Blog` posts you want to publish to `approved` from the admin panel. Your `.save()` method will automatically publish those; and change the ones that have already been published to `pending`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think the solution will be very simple like this. Your solution was great and very easy to understand. Thanks again.